# Difference between "i", "й" and "та"

Tags: граматика, сполучники, милозвучність

So, in Ukrainian we have `i`, `й` and `та` - I'm not a native speaker and while I more o less understand when it's better to use `й` rather than `i` - this understanding is not complete. Also, I don't understand at all when `та` should be (or could be?) chosen.

Can somebody provide set of exact rules one can apply - if such set exists of course.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Functionally, all three are very close and can be used interchangeably.

## "І" vs. "Й"

The rules of **vowel harmony** apply. They are listed in numerous places, but let me simplify it a bit. (Warning, this would contradict the mainstream).

**Use `й` if:**

- At the beginning of a sentence, and the first word begins with a non-palatalized vowel *а, о, у, е, и, і*:

  > **Й і**сторію треба вивчати
- Between the two vowels:

  > Оксан**а й І**рина

**Otherwise, use `і`,** however:

**Between the vowel and consonant** (in any order), depend on the vowel harmony as there exist examples of each usage:

- Vowel-**і**-Consonant:

  > *Орися крутнулас**я і п**обігла по ріллі* — Григір Тютюнник;
  >   *Горобц**і і В**ишня* — Євген Гребінка (назва твору)
- Vowel-**й**-Consonant:

  > *Навчає баєчка великог**о й м**алого* — Л. Глібов
- Consonant-**і**-Vowel:

  > *У річку сніг побі**г, і О**ржиця заграла* — Євген Гребінка;
- Consonant-**й**-Vowel:

  > *Мазепі здавалося, тільки вмовкне, одразу оддаленіє од кошового, випаде з його думо**к, й о**пиниться він у руках козаків, а тоді…* — Юрій Мушкетик

**Note**. As usual, you can step off the rules to convey emotions, either positive or negative.

> *Тристан блукав по лісі, ловив зелений шум, хотів йому віддати своє коханн**я й с**ум* — Леся Українка

**Note**. There are other words with interchangeable *і/й*, most notable one is *йти/іти* (to go). The same rules apply usage.

## Using "та"

- *Та* can't be used for enumeration:

  > *Місяць пливе оглядать і небо, і зорі, і землю, і море* — Тарас Шевченко
- However, *та* can be used for pairwise enumeration. The quote above can be re-phrased:

  > *Місяць пливе оглядать небо **та** зорі, землю **та** море*
- *Та*, unlike the others, can be used as "but"/"but then":

  > *Світить місяць у віконце, **та** в очах темніє* — Петро Гулак-Артемовський
  >   *Хоч ізійшлися і раненько, **та** пан Еней наш опізнивсь* — Іван Котляревський
  >   *І там степи, і тут степи, **Та** тут не такії, Руді, руді, аж червоні, А там голубії* — Т. Шевченко

---

Sources:

- BBC: Блог професора Пономарів [Про різницю між сполучниками "І", "Й", "ТА"](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv/2011/01/post-40.html)

Answer (score 12):

The [choice](https://www.ar25.org/article/vzhyvannya-spoluchnykiv-i-y-ta.html) of і/й is mostely euphonic. Use `i`:

- At the beginning of a sentence before a consonant sound: *І тоді він сказав ...* - "And then he said ..." and after a pause marked with a punctuation sign: *і дні, і ночі* - "And days, and nights".
- Between a word that ends in a consonant and a word that begins with a consonant: *Степа**н** і **П**етро*.
- After a word that ends in a vowel if the next word begins with letters **й**, **є**, **ї**, **ю**, **я** (that is with the sound [j]): *Ян**а** і **Ю**рко*.
- When notion are contrasted: *батьки і діти* "parents and children", *світло і темрява* "light and dark".

Use `й`:

- Between vowel letters, except when the second word starts with **є**, **ї**, **ю**, **я**: *Оксан**а** й **О**лег*, but *Оксан**а** і **Є**вген*.

Use `та`:

- For sylistic diversity in any of the abovementioned cases, especially if the sentence already contains `i`: *Олег **і** Паша зайшли **та** сіли.* "Oleh and Pashe entered and sat down."
- In the meaning of "but": *Він обіцяв, та не прийшов*. "He promised but didn't come."

Comment: Shouldn't you also add examples `Яна та Юрко`, `Оксана та Євген`, which to my mind are equally good? Or is there a rule that actually forbids this? The examples you gave could be emphasizing the difference between the use of `і` and `й`, but should not be read as precluding the use of `та`.

Comment: @SassaNF - Haven't I written that `та` can be used "in any of the abovementioned cases"?

Comment: At the beginning of the sentence you should use "i" not only before consonants but also before **я ю є ї й**.

Comment: @P.Vovk - If a sentence begins with letters **я ю є ї й**, thiat means it begins with a consonant _sound_, and in my answer it is "Use `i`: - At the beginning of a sentence before a consonant sound".

Comment: @yellow sky i suppose for a non-native speaker it would be a problem to distinguish between consonants and consonant sounds. Therefore, your answer is a right one, but not clear enough for a foreigner.

Answer (score 1):

[Ось тут](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/orfografiya/cherguvannya-i-y-ta) ті самі правила милозвучності вживання `і`, `й`, `та`. Вони викладені простіше й українською мовою. Мене вже з тиждень дістає питання - коли який сполучник треба писати. 
[image: Милозвучнійсть: І, Й, ТА]

Мабуть також варто дублювати не-україномовні питання і відповіді українською, чи створювати окрему тему українською

Comment: -1 for two reasons: (1) this answer essentially duplicates the existing answer, adding no extra value; (2) The question was posted in English, and [our policy](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/) is to provide answers in the language of the question.

Comment: бачу. **Keep both.** я мав створити окреме Q&A українською.